# Guideline for writing lexer Vs parser rules

Tags: antlr4

Can anyone help me understand the behavior of a rule written at Lexer Vs Parser levels?

```
basicInterfaceType 
    : ('Port-channel' | 'fortyGigE' | 'TenGigabitEthernet' | 'GigabitEthernet')
;
```

The above parser rule returned the expected value `TenGigabitEthernet` when accessed as `ctx.basicInterfaceType().getText()` whereas the following rule returned `null` when accessed as `ctx.BASIC_INTF_TYPE().getText()`, `null` being returned at `BASIC_INTF_TYPE()`

```
BASIC_INTF_TYPE
    : ('Port-channel' | 'fortyGigE' | 'TenGigabitEthernet' | 'GigabitEthernet')
;
```

Is there a guideline like put-too-many-keyword-alternatives-at-parser ? How is the `null` return valid for the above lexer rule?

Answer (score 1):

When `getText()` returns null it usually means that the sub-rule or token you're querying wasn't used (wasn't found in the input). Possibly in the second case it was being matched as a different token. The order of lexer rules matters; when it can't decide which token to match, it goes with the one that appears first in the grammar file. Parser rules are more flexible--the way you've defined yours it can match any tokens that contain the specified text.

I'm assuming you didn't have both of these defined at the same time, I could certainly see that having confusing results. Your parser rule defines pseudo-tokens, which appear before other lexer rules, and might therefore prevent your token rule from ever being able to match.

Comment: I never used both in place. Your answer directs me to understand more on pseudo-token, thanks!!!